# In Every Request New Session is Generating in the web api

Tags: c#, .net, session, asp.net-core-2.0

Whenever a new request get hit in the controller new session id do generate at that time so i keep lost the previous value.

Using .net Core API 2.2.0

"Startup.cs"

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false; // Default is true, make it false
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
```

Comment: add  app.UseSession(); in Configure in startup.

Comment: I also added it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're dealing with an API. If I had to guess, you're not passing the `Cookie` header with each request, using the value that the server returned initially via the `Set-Cookie` response header. A web browser handles this type of thing automatically for web application requests. However, an API is a different bag, and you'll need to do it manually.

That said, APIs are *supposed* to be stateless, and as a result do not generally support the idea of sessions and/or cookies. You should not utilize `Session` with an API project, at all. Each request should contain all data necessary to service that request. Otherwise, you'll introduce all sorts of problems into your API.